# Adding Sign in with Apple to capabilities in Xcode

Tags: apple-sign-in, apple-developer-account

I have a paid Apple developer account which I get the "Sign in with Apple" option when I'm trying add it to the capabilities. But there's another Apple developer account which my client invited me with my email. I want to use that account to add "Sign in with Apple" to capabilities but I can't find that option. Can someone please help me to find what's the issue? My client has a paid account.
[image]

[image]